# Cursor not changing when hovering over links in Xamarin WebView on Mac if the main window has no title bar

Tags: c#, macos, xamarin, webview

I created a simple Xamarin-App for Mac without title bar. I added just a WebView control to the view and loaded an URL (https://www.google.com). The page is displayed correctly but when hovering over links the cursor does not change to the hand-cursor.

If the Title Bar is enabled for the main window everything works fine. It seems that this issue is related to NSWindow styles?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same issue and found a workaround. First you need to enable the Title bar in the storyboard and hide it from code.
Here is the code I used:

```
        Window.TitleVisibility = NSWindowTitleVisibility.Hidden;
        Window.TitlebarAppearsTransparent = true;
        Window.StyleMask |= NSWindowStyle.FullSizeContentView;
```